# Send data with AJAX and receive in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, each

I'm having a script which is generating a JSON array, based values user have selected. These values are sent as a JSON with AJAX to a PHP script which should receive this values and process it.

What could be wrong?

JSON (That is sent):

```
[{
  "Pages":
         {"name":" Page Name 1",
          "id":"252456436636644"}
         },
  {
   "Pages":{
          "name":" Page Name 2",
          "id":"345345435435232"
          }
}]
```

Jquery:

```
var json_pages = JSON.stringify(publish);

$.ajax({
    url: "post.php",
    type: "post",
    data: { PublishToPages: json_pages },
    success: function(){},
    error: function(){}   
});
```

Problem is that the JSON I recieve from PHP isn't getting the data,

```
if($_POST['PublishToPages']) {

    $json = $_POST['PublishToPages'];

    $array = json_decode($json, true);

    foreach($array as $item) { 
        $page_id = $item['Pages']['id'];
        echo $page_id;  
    }
}
```

If I manually put in the JSON in the PHP script like this it Works,

```
if ($_POST['PublishToPages']) {

    $json = '[{"Pages":{"name":" Page Name","id":"234545355345435"}},{"Pages":{"name":" Page Name 2","id":"345345435435435435"}}]';

    $array = json_decode($json, true);

    foreach($array as $item) { 
    $page_id = $item['Pages']['id'];
        echo $page_id;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check what's inside $array ?

Comment: Try after adding this  dataType:"json", to ajax.

Comment: If you do "console.log(publish)" after line "var json_pages = JSON.stringify(publish);" what is the result? And what does the http request shows you? Is the data sent to server?

Comment: Try adding `var_dump($_POST['PublishToPages'])` to your PHP code. What does it output?

Comment: Thanks @EswaraReddy I tried adding dataType:"json", but then it immediately gave me an "error" in the ajax. It should be put like this?             $.ajax({
                url: "post.php",
                type: "post",
                dataType:"json",

Comment: If I do a var_dump I get this: [{\"Pages\":{\"name\":\" Page Name\",\"id\":\"9234939284234334\"}}]

Comment: So it could be due to an encoding error? So what should I use here? stripslashes?

Comment: Check what you send with console.log in javascript, and what you get with var_dump. May be you didn`t send anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
if($_POST['PublishToPages']) {

    $json = $_POST['PublishToPages'];
    $items = array();

    $array = json_decode($json, true);

    foreach($array as $item) { 
        $page_id = $item['Pages']['id'];
        $items[] = $page_id;  
    }

    echo json_encode($items);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "post.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType:"json",
    data: { PublishToPages: json_pages },
    success: function(){},
    error: function(){}   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all input! I figured it out using the var_dump and realized it was encoding error so added stripslashes(); and it worked! :)

```
if ($_POST['PublishToPages']) {

    $json = stripslashes($_POST['PublishToPages']);

    $array = json_decode($json, true);

    foreach($array as $item) { 
        $page_id = $item['Pages']['id'];
        echo $page_id;  
    }
}
```